# cte1 is invalid object name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

### The question was

> Does the customer who has placed the maximum number of orders have
>   the maximum rating?

*with tables orders,customers and salespeople*

I tried to solve it using CTE but it gave me errors. The code which I wrote was

```
;with cte1 as (
select count(onum) cnt,cnum
from sql_practice.practice.Orders o 
group by cnum)

select * from cte1 where cnt=(
select max(cnt) from (select count(onum) cnt,cnum
from sql_practice.practice.Orders o 
group by cnum)A)

;with cte2 as(select cnum from sql_practice.practice.Customer where rating in(select max(RATING) from 
sql_practice.practice.Customer))

select * from cte2,cte1 where cte2.CNUM=cte1.cnum;
```

In the above query cte1 was identified as an invalid object

Comment: A CTE is an expression, not an object. It can only be referenced in the statement it is declared in. Your second statement, (beginning with `select * from cte2,cte1`) only has `cte2` declared, and so `cte1` has no context in that statement. Other notes: `;` is a statement terminator, not a "beginningator", it goes at the end of your SQL statements, not the start (or start of statements that require the **previous** statement to have been terminated properly). Also [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: If you want to reference `cte1` again in the second statement, you'll need to declare it again.

Answer (score 0):

The Limitation of CTE is that the Scope of a Cte it only till the next line after the CTE declaration. So You can't use the CTE after that.

Which means in your case The CTE1 ends it's scope on the line when you are checking the cnt against the MAX(cnt) and hence it can't be referred further.

There are 2 Solutions for this.

First one is to use Either Temp table or Table variable instead of the CTE.

but Looking at your Requirement. I think the following Approach will solve your problem better

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        C.cnum,
        MaxOnum = MAX(O.Onum) OVER(PARTITION BY NULL),
        MaxRating = MAX(C.Rating) OVER(PARTITION BY NULL)
        FROM sql_practice.practice.Orders O
            INNER JOIN sql_practice.practice.Customer C
                ON C.CNUM = O.Cnum
)
SELECT
    *
    WHERE MaxOnum = MaxRating
```

Answer (score 0):

A cte can only be used immediatly after creating it. Then, you can't use cte1 after do an extra select query and create cte2

If you want to do a select query with your two ctes you need this query

```
;with cte1 as (
    select count(onum) cnt,cnum
    from sql_practice.practice.Orders o 
    group by cnum)
,cte2 as
    (select cnum from sql_practice.practice.Customer where rating in(select max(RATING) 
    from sql_practice.practice.Customer))

select * from cte2
inner join cte1 on cte2.CNUM=cte1.cnum;
```

Comment: I'd fix that old style join here at least (although the "beginningator" still bugs me :) )

Comment: I agree, fixed ;) thx